# Sort function is crashing the file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that sorts a table using column O and then N.

```vb
Sub SortKV1()
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("KV1").Sort
         .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("O3"), Order:=xlDescending
         .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("N3"), Order:=xlDescending
         .SetRange Range("Query_KV1")
         .Header = xlNo
         .Apply
         Application.Goto ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("KV1").Cells(1, 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

When I save and open the file again there is an error.
[image: First error when opening the file again]

It has to be repaired.
[image: Description of repair of Excel file]

I tried rebuilding the worksheet from scratch but it did not help.
I have the VBA code in a module and call it using an ActiveX button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some early drawbacks with `Sort` object I resolved not to use it any more and switch to `Sort()` method of `Range` object

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("KV1").Range("Query_KV1").Sort _
    key1:=Range("O3"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo, _
    key2:=Range("N3"), order2:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
```

Comment: Works like a charm, many thanks. Just for some reason it only worked when I had the sheet in question opened so I added another go-to function to the start and made it work. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. But all VBA stataments act on open workbooks sheets!

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear `SortFields` after & before Sort:

```
Dim customList As Variant
Dim lastRow as Long

customList = Array("0000", "0100", "0200", "0300", "0400", "0500", "0600", "0700", "0800", "0900", "1000", "1100", "1200", "1300", "1400", "1500", "1600", "1700", "1800", "1900", "2000", "2100", "2200", "2300")
lastRow = Sheet2.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=customList

Sheet2.Sort.SortFields.Clear

With Sheet2.Sort
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), Order:=xlAscending
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1"), Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:=Application.CustomListCount
     .SetRange Range("A1", "H" & lastRow)
     .Header = xlYes
     .Apply
End With

Sheet2.Sort.SortFields.Clear
Application.DeleteCustomList Application.CustomListCount
```

Since I put `Sheet2.Sort.SortFields.Clear` before and after sorting, spreadsheet is no longer crashing.